# ServiceBase.OnShutdown and event logs in Windows .Net 3.5

Tags: windows, service, events, logging

I've written a custom service that overrides ServiceBase.OnShutdown().
Unfortunately, when I log to the event log, nothing is written.
My guess is that the Windows event log was shut down before my service.
Is there a way to order service shutdown so that my servce shuts down
before the event logger? I don't want to have to write out to a file.
Pl. advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to setup a dependency where your service depends on the Event logger, this is mostly done to make them load in the correct order but I assume that might make sure that your service always was stopped first as well.
As can be seen in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963243.aspx) Technet article, you'd need to change the `DependOnService` value either using the `Sc.exe` tool or the `ChangeServiceConfig` API.

Comment: fyi - I saw some post somewhere (not very helpful I know) that said this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it is more or less a Reflection-Hack.
I added my solution to an other post: [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b7d82c3-e7d6-471f-b085-d46e7de9c737/service-not-doing-onstop-or-onshutdown-when-windows-shuts-down?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required)

Hope I could help.